# Erro ao somar cada linha de uma matriz 5x3

Tags: c, array, matriz, soma

Ola, estou tendo um problema ao somar cada uma das linhas da minha matriz e armazenar em um vetor

o meu codigo esta assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int conta(int * matriz[5][3], int * vet)
{
for (int i = 0 ; i<5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<3;j++)
        {
            matriz [i][j] = i+j;

            vet[i] += matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void imprimir(int * matriz[5][3], int * vet)
{
for (int i = 0 ; i<5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<3;j++)
        {
            printf("%d",matriz [i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        printf("soma linha %d : %d \n", i , vet[i] );
    }
}
void main()
{
int matriz [5][3];
int vet[5] = {0};

conta(matriz,vet);
imprimir(matriz,vet);
}
```

por algum motivo ele retorna:

```
soma linha 0 : 6
soma linha 1 : 27
soma linha 2 : 48
soma linha 3 : 69
soma linha 4 : 90
```

e não :

```
soma linha 0 : 3
soma linha 1 : 6
soma linha 2 : 9
soma linha 3 : 12
soma linha 4 : 15
```

que deveria ser sua resposta.

alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow em português Miguel. Eu reverti a sua edição do titulo com "Resolvido" pois não é a forma como o site funciona. A indicação que é dada com a seta verde numa resposta só por si já indica se resolveu o seu problema ou não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está nos parâmetros que tem nas funções que estão incorretos:

```
int conta(int * matriz[5][3], int * vet)
//            ^-- aqui

void imprimir(int * matriz[5][3], int * vet)
//                ^-- e aqui
```

Da forma que está, as funções recebem ponteiros para matrizes de duas dimensões, que não é o que você passa no `main`. Para além disso a função `conta` tem o tipo de retorno como `int` mas não devolve nenhum valor. A lógica em si da soma está correta, assim como a respetiva atribuição na matriz.

Corrigido os problemas que apontei fica assim:

```
void conta(int matriz[5][3], int * vet){
    // ...
}

void imprimir(int matriz[5][3], int * vet){
    // ...
}
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/JU5mPp)

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que, na sua função `int conta`, `vet[i]` precisa ser incrementado por `i + j`.

A função completa fica desta maneira:

```
int conta(int * matriz[5][3], int *vet)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i<5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<3;j++)
        {
            matriz [i][j] = i+j;
            vet[i] += i+j;
        }
    }
}
```